# JavaFx custom control architecture - handling focus and key events

Tags: javafx, combobox, custom-controls, skin

I am trying to create **custom controls** for my JavaFx app and I got a bit lost in the  correct architecture of the code.

I have created a **custom combobox control**, which is based on detailed **customization** of the default `ComboBox` control. Since, after the customization, I cannot guarantee the general function of the control as ComboBox type (some methods could "spoil" my customization etc.), I thought the correct way is the encapsulation using this architecture:

1. My `CustomComboControl` extends `Control`, not `ComboBox`.
2. It contains a private field `internalCombo`, which is my customized `ComboBox` instance. The internal combo is a part of the custom control, not of its skin, so that I can easily get data from the internal combo, delegate things to internal combo etc.
3. My `CustomComboControl` uses a custom `Skin`, which uses the internal combo from the control as its root node.

**Is this a correct architecture?** It seems generally to work well but I encountered some problems I cannot solve.

**Focus and key events**. If I keep both my custom control and the internal combo `setFocusTraversable(true)`, the focus seems to be doubled in going through focus cycle (need to press TAB twice to go over my custom control).

If I make only the internal combo focustraversable, I cannot listen for focus on my custom control (which is sometimes needed).

If I make only the custom control focustraversable, the internal combo does not receive keyboard events, which breaks its function.

What is the correct architecture? (I know that this question is probably too broad.)

Question EDITed:

**In the second suggested solution (only skin focustraversable, not the control itself) is passing key events from the custom control to the internal combo somehow possible?**

Comment: basically, your question is too broad for this site, so it's likely to be closed because it cannot be answered in a concise manner: the options and your constraints are too diffuse. That said: something like _detailed customization_ sounds fishy like you might be on a suboptimal path and doctoring on symptoms that were introduced by that path. In your shoes, I would also explore the options to either extend the combo and provide custom skin/behavior or start with comboBoxBase and -skin.

Comment: @kleopatra Thank you, I understand, OK, my fault. If I reduce the question (see edit) to the last one (passing key events from control to skin), can this be answered?